# The originating IP address of an HTTP Request is different than application IP address?

Tags: .net, windows, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, windows-server-2012

I have an ASP.Net MVC application that has a method which in turn makes a HTTP Request to an outside service. The IP of the application is 192.168.1.100 the server also has an IP of 192.168.1.3 bound to the nic card. I am curious as to why when the request is made from within the Asp.Net application it looks like it is originating from 192.168.1.3 rather than 192.168.1.100.

Comment: "from within the application", e.g. the server's talking to itself? It'd be free to use whatever IP it wants for the outgoing request, even if that request just turns right around and comes back in side. by default windows would choose the interface with the best metric, which would be the primary/initial nic.

Comment: @MarcB, it actually is calling a web service outside the network. So I would guess it is just picking up the initial IP?

Comment: @MarcB, if you want to make that the answer, I'd like to give you credit for that.